# No Results coming back from pouchdb-find query

Tags: pouchdb

Trying to do query on JSON below, getting empty array back from query, any clues, this is the first time I have user pouchDb and pouchDb-find.

groupId is passed in as parameter, create index is wrapped in a promise then I call, _db.find after the index is created.

```
_db.createIndex({
    index: {
        fields: ['og_group_ref.und[0].target_id', 'type']
    }

 _db.find({
    selector: {
        "og_group_ref.und[0].target_id": groupId
        //type: 'student'
    }

JSON
"og_group_ref": {"und": [{"target_id": "49"}]},
```

Any examples of complex selectors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a particular element in an array is not supported by the Mango selector syntax. You will have to move the field out of the array; sorry.

**Edit:** Actually, as a hack, I think you could do `og_group_ref.und.0.target_id`, but I don't know if that works in Cloudant. It might only work in PouchDB.

Comment: Is this a feature that is coming, thanks for your response.

Comment: No, not that I know of.